What is this black square on this crime scene photo in Longlegs?

In the movie, Longlegs, when FBI agent Lee is investigating the serial killer called Longlegs; she browses through a number of photos taken from the crime scene, including this one photo with a black square to its middle left.
Was it caused by incorrect exposure during film developing? What purpose does it serve?

Not sure, I haven't seen the movie but it looks like something was deliberately obscured in the frame when the photo was printed.

Not an answer but I wanted to note that the crime scene, of the Horn family 'murder-suicide', has several photos of the same area, with differing details, and one of which is used for promotion (and poster) of the movie, and you can see what the square might be obscuring:

Perhaps it is something that was obscured for the movie in-universe but left in other shots as a clue for the audience.
Variations are:

square covering everything in this area
dish of some kind, blood splatters
white roll of some kind, dish removed, same blood splatters
crime scene, 'crime scene marker no.52', where previous items above were, blood splatters remain

I am unsure of when it appears in the movie, and why the other shots of the same scene are not obscured in any way though it suggests variations of the crime scene over time (from discovery to forensics)
An in-universe reason, perhaps, is that they obscure it for reasons of hiding the blood splatter, as a form of censorship to whoever it is to be shown to?

I'm thinking they obscured the evidence number to avoid confusion over which piece of evidence the photo is looking at.

interesting, yes, that could be an idea. I have yet to see the movie though... Heard polarized opinions about it
